# Integration of the product of an entire function and a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, entire-functions

Let $f$ have only poles on the complex plane. Suppose that for every polynomial $p(z)$ and every closed curve $C$ not passing through the poles of $f$ we have: $$\int_C p(z)f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z = 0.$$ Prove that $f$ is entire.

I thought about the "Closed Curve Theorem" for entire functions so that $p(z)f(z)$ has to be entire. But I couldn't relate the functions poles being on the complex plane. If you can show me how to approach, I will appreciate.

Comment: Let $g$ have a pole at $a$. Find a polynomial $p$ and a closed curve $C$ such that $\int_C p(z)g(z)\,dz \neq 0$.

Comment: Additional hint: Try @Daniel's approach for a pole of order 1 (a simple pole) first.